# TypoScript: Change wrap of header field when there is no IMG_RESOURCE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I've a jumbotron with a background image and a header inside.
The background image comes from the site properties, the header from a specific backend layout column.

**current state**
The jumbotron works perfectly with the background image and the header. But now I would like to change the css class of my header depending on whether an image is in the site properties or not.

**how the result should look like (pseudo code)**

```
if there is an image:
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(...)
    <h1 class="header-type1">My header with standard styling</h1>
  </div>
else:
  <h1 class="header-type2">My header with different styling</h1>
```

**This is my typoscript code**

```
lib.jumbo < lib.dynamicContent
lib.jumbo {
    20.renderObj = COA
    20.renderObj {
        5 = IMG_RESOURCE
        5 {
            file {
                import = uploads/media/
                import.data = levelmedia:-1
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                import.listNum = 0
                width = 1022
                height = 472
            }
            stdWrap {
                wrap = <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(|);">
                required = 1
            }
        }

        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            stdWrap {
                field = header
                required = 1
                
                # if there is one image in the site properties use this wrap
                wrap = <h1 class="header-type1">|</h1>
                
                # if there is no image:
                wrap < h1 class="header-type2">|</h1>
            }
        }

        # this one should only be displayed too, if there is an image
        90 = TEXT
        90.value = </div>
    }
}
```

`lib.DynamicContent` comes from the [bootstrap package](https://github.com/sebkln/basetemplate9/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/lib.dynamicContent.typoscript)

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a case where the typoscript solution will be a little complicated. But meanwhile we have alternatives:

**Why don't you use FLUID for your rendering?**

```
lib.jumbo < lib.dynamicContent
lib.jumbo {
    20.renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    20.renderObj {
        template = Header
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:my_site_ext/Resources/Private/page/Templates

        variables {
            header = TEXT
            header.field = header

        jumboImage = IMG_RESOURCE
        jumboImage {
            file {
                import = uploads/media/
                import.data = levelmedia:-1
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                import.listNum = 0
                width = 1022
                height = 472
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and in the referenced fluid template file:

```xml
<f:if condition="{jumboImage}">
<f:then>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url({jumboImage})">
        <h1 class="header-type1">{header->f:format.raw()}</h1>
    </div>
</f:if>
<f:else>
    <h1 class="header-type2">{header->f:format.raw()}</h1>
</f:else>
</f:if>
```

note:
the image generation could be optimized

---

**I assume you even do not need this typoscript at all** as you probably use the `lib.jumbo` like `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.jumbo" arguments="..." />`

At that place you could use a partial or just a section with a call to the `{f:uri.image image="..."}` viewhelper.